# Derived model in Rails uses incorrect foreign key on associations, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sti

Using STI in a Rails 4.2 app that manages members and donors of an NGO, I have a base model Friend...

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

... and a derived model Member with certain associations only for Member, not for Friend:

```
class Member < Friend # This is STI!
  has_one :membership
  ...
end
```

When I build a new membership...

```
member = Member.new
membership = member.build_membership
```

... Rails crashes:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'member_id' for Membership.
```

The `memberships` table contains a `friend_id`, not a `member_id` column.

How do I get Rails to use the correct `friend_id` column, rather than the `member_id` column that does not exist?

I've tried

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, foreign_key: 'friend_id'
  ...
end
```

-- to no avail.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the `foreign_key` parameter in the `Member` class as well:

```
class Member < Friend # This is STI!
  has_one :membership, foreign_key: 'friend_id'
  ...
end
```

In other words, if you want to use the methods added by the `has_one` call, it does not suffice to specify the foreign key in the class that holds the foreign key.